# Python: IDE support to output database query like pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

(This may be stupid question due to my ignorance.)

Is it possible in Visual Studio Code or PyCharm (perhaps with a plugin) to automatically output a database query, say from an Sqlite source, be nicely formatted like a Pandas DataFrame? (So when I run the code it will be displayed in a nicely formatted table.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .format(), there are a few different ways you could do this - I'd normally do something like this:

```
    print('{:>len(longestResult)}'.format(i))
```

If you iterate through all your results to find the longest one and use the length of it as above and iterate through your results again it'll give you a nicely padded table.